# State doesen't get updated and generell problems with infiniteScroll

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Im using React with Typescript and Next.Js
I have a REST Api which returns me a paged result.
I have now implemented an infinite scroll list which, when I scroll, updates the skip so that new data gets fetched.
For this i used a Loader which sits at the end of the list and load new data when the the loader enters the screen. I check this using an observer:

```
const RecordsLoader: React.FC<RecordsLoaderProps> = ({ onScreenEnter }): JSX.Element => {
  const ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLSpanElement> = useRef<HTMLSpanElement>(null);
  const [inScreen, setInScreen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer: IntersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]: Array<IntersectionObserverEntry>) => {
      setInScreen(entry.isIntersecting);
    });

    observer.observe(ref.current);

    return () => {
      observer.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inScreen) onScreenEnter();
  }, [inScreen]);

  // inline styles are used to overcome the automatic padding and background-color assignment of the no-background grid container
  return <span style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent', padding: '0' }} ref={ref} />;
};
```

On screen enter gets handeled by this method:

```
 const handleScreenEnter = (): void => {
    if(!page.isValidating) setSkipTake({skip: skipTake.skip + pageSize, take: skipTake.take});
  };
```

And my Page in this case is an SWRResponse:

```
const page: SWRResponse<AllRecords, RequestError> = useSWRImmutable(
    'records',
    () => getIndexRecords(index.id, skipTake),
    {
      use: [addAuth],
      suspense:true
    }
  );
```

and these are my states and variables that are used

```
  const pageSize: number = 10;
  const [skipTake, setSkipTake] = useState<SkipTake>({ take: pageSize, skip: 0 });
  const [records, setRecords] = useState<AllRecords>(null);
```

And when the skipTake gets updated i mutate the page:

```
useEffect(() => {
    page.mutate();
    setRecords({page: {...page.data.page, skip: 0}, items: records?.items?.concat(page.data.items) ?? []});
  }, [skipTake]);
```

This works.
Only problem is now that sometimes the list is not long enough to push the loader out of the screen, thus i cant start scrolling and then cant get new data.

Now my idea is to check after the first data is fetched if the InScreen state is still true and if  yes triggeer OnScreenEnter again.

To achieve this, I simply added OnScrenEnter to the useEffect

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (inScreen) onScreenEnter();
  }, [inScreen, onScreenEnter]);
```

This should work, tho it triggers to many times beacause obviously the data isnt fetched instantly and results in triggering onScreenEnter to many times but this is not the only problem. I also get the same results over and over?
I tried loging out the the skipTake before and after the setting:

```
const handleScreenEnter = (): void => {
    console.log("before", skipTake);
    if(!page.isValidating) setSkipTake({skip: skipTake.skip + pageSize, take: skipTake.take});
    console.log("after", skipTake);
  };
```

But the logs AND the RESULTS on the site show that it wont get new data because skip doesen't get updated somehow. Now I Thought maybe it doesent update instantly but even after waiting some time it haven't got updated.

Can you tell me why this happens and how i can change that? I am also very thankfull for other better methods to do this if there are any.